# I do not see the save button on my form even though I have set it up in Admin Area Magento

Tags: php, forms, magento

I am new to mangeto framework and i am learning to create a form in admin area section. However, it has been over hours that I could not figure out the error i am receiving:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to      Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given, called in /vagrant/magento/app/code/local/MasteringMagento/Example/controllers/Adminhtml/EventController.php on line 12.

The following is my Edit.php file as well as my Form.php file
Edit.php:

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Adminhtml_EventController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{
public function indexAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_addContent(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('example/adminhtml_event_edit'));
    //go straight to the php file to render the form. otherwise this will not perfomed.
    $this->renderLayout();
}
public function saveAction(){
    $eventID = $this->getRequest()->getParam('event_id');
    $eventModel = Mage::getModel('example/event')->load($eventID);
    if($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()){
        try{
            $eventModel->addData($data)->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Your event has been saved')
            );
        }catch(Exception $e){
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }
}
```

}

and Form.php file:

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Event_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form{
protected function _prepareForm(){
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id'=>'edit_form',
        'action'=>$this->getData('action'), 'method'=>'post'));

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset',
        array('legend'=>Mage::helper('example')->__('General Information'),
            'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'label' => Mage::helper('example')->__('Event Name'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('example')->__('Event Name'),
        'required' => true
    ));

    $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(
        Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
    $fieldset->addField('start', 'date', array(
        'name' => 'start',
        'format' => $dateFormatIso,
        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'label' => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
        'required' => true
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('end', 'date', array(
        'name' => 'end',
        'format' => $dateFormatIso,
        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'label' => Mage::helper('example')->__('End Date'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('example')->__('End Date'),
        'required' => true
    ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

}

The error i think is from my Controller. However, if i direct the url link to the form, it will display. But if i direct to its container which is Edit.php, the error above would occurs:

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Adminhtml_EventController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{
public function indexAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_addContent(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('example/adminhtml_event_edit'));
    //go straight to the php file to render the form. otherwise this will not perfomed.
    $this->renderLayout();
}}
```

This is my config.xml. I did include the base class for Magento Blocks:

```
<blocks>
        <example>
            <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Block</class>
        </example>
    </blocks>
```

Please help me to identify the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createBlock()` is an abstract factory pattern for Blocks inside of Magento. Whenever Magento cannot resolve a factory class from this method, a boolean is returned... which is the case in your example, as the error message says.

Check your class `MasteringMagento_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Event_Edit` for spelling, casing, or class related errors. Also ensure that your class file is located at `app/code/local/MasteringMagento/Example/Block/Adminhtml/Event/Edit.php`.

Answer (score 0):

In magento, every admin form block is loaded first by a form container.

Here, you call MasteringMagento_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Event_Edit class :

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('example/adminhtml_event_edit')
```

This class, located in **app/code/local/MasteringMagento/Example/Block/Adminhtml/Post/Edit.php**, should look to something like this :

```
<?php
/**
 * MasteringMagento_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Post_Edit
 */
class MasteringMagento_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Post_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // $this->_objectId = 'id';
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_blockGroup      = 'example';
        $this->_controller      = 'adminhtml_post';
        $this->_mode            = 'edit';
        $modelTitle = $this->_getModelTitle();
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', $this->_getHelper()->__("Save $modelTitle"));
        $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
            'label'     => $this->_getHelper()->__('Save and Continue Edit'),
            'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
            'class'     => 'save',
        ), -100);

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    protected function _getHelper(){
        return Mage::helper('example');
    }

    protected function _getModel(){
        return Mage::registry('exemple_youmodel');
    }

    protected function _getModelTitle(){
        return 'Post';
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        $model = $this->_getModel();
        $modelTitle = $this->_getModelTitle();
        if ($model && $model->getId()) {
           return $this->_getHelper()->__("Edit $modelTitle (ID: {$model->getId()})");
        }
        else {
           return $this->_getHelper()->__("New $modelTitle");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Get URL for back (reset) button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/index');
    }

    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', array($this->_objectId => $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->_objectId)));
    }

}
```

As you can see, all your buttons are set in the __construct() method.

Hope it helps.